# Jmeter - How to fetch IDs from a json response and use it in the next request

Tags: jmeter

From a JSON response of the format below,

```
{"data":[{"id":"xxx","data":{"A":"111","B":"222","C":"333"}},{"id":"yyy","data":{"A":"111","B":"222","C":"333"}}]
```

I need to fetch only IDs and pass it in the next request as a list like

```
{"data":["xxx","yyy"]}
```

I was able to fetch all these IDs using a Regular Expression Extractor with the following values.

```
Reference Name = data ; 
Regex = "id":"(.+?)" ;
Template = $1$ ;
Match No = -1 ;
```

The IDs retrieved are in the following format.

```
data_1 = xxx
data_2 = yyy
```

But the IDs could be a lot, so I need an efficient way where I can use just one variable instead of using `{"data":["data_1","data_2"]}` and so on.

Comment: What code I can use if I want to get value 111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a single variable out of these `data_1`, `data_2`, etc. as follows:

1. Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) **after** your Regular Expression Extractor
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   dataBuilder.append("{\"data\":[");

   int ids = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("data_matchNr"));
   for (int i = 1; i <= ids; i++) {

       dataBuilder.append("\"").append(vars.get("data_" + i)).append("\"");
       if (i < ids) {
           dataBuilder.append(",");
       }

   }

   dataBuilder.append("]}");

   vars.put("data", dataBuilder.toString());
   ```

Above code will concatenate all the variables prefixed with `data_` coming from the Regular Expression Extractor into a single JSON array. You can refer the resulting value as `${data}` where required.

References:

- [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)